# Why does PKCE for Oauth2.0 hash the ascii bytes instead of the original bytes?

Tags: oauth2

Maybe this is not a useful question, but I got a little hung up on this because it seems a little strange. In the example of the PKCE verification in [RFC-7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#appendix-B) it details the following:

```
The client uses output of a suitable random number generator to
   create a 32-octet sequence.  The octets representing the value in
   this example (using JSON array notation) are:

      [116, 24, 223, 180, 151, 153, 224, 37, 79, 250, 96, 125, 216, 173,
      187, 186, 22, 212, 37, 77, 105, 214, 191, 240, 91, 88, 5, 88, 83,
      132, 141, 121]

   Encoding this octet sequence as base64url provides the value of the
   code_verifier:

       dBjftJeZ4CVP-mB92K27uhbUJU1p1r_wW1gFWFOEjXk

   The code_verifier is then hashed via the SHA256 hash function to
   produce:

     [19, 211, 30, 150, 26, 26, 216, 236, 47, 22, 177, 12, 76, 152, 46,
      8, 118, 168, 120, 173, 109, 241, 68, 86, 110, 225, 137, 74, 203,
      112, 249, 195]
```

The part that seems strange is that the bytes from the first random byte sequence are not hashed to generate the challenge, the ascii bytes of the base64url-encoded string are hashed. Is there any reason for this? Why not just hash the original bytes?

Comment: My opinion: if you ever need to send the `code_verifier` somewhere, binary data can be troublesome. Base64 data is easier.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Yes, i agree. That explains why the data is base64 encoded, but I'm wondering why the encoded string is hashed instead of the binary data. Why not hash it, and then encode the result?

Comment: Design decisions. Designer is free to use whatever he wants, and the world is free to use as designed, or create another thing. In this case, there's no pressing need to change how it works, so we go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the code_verifier is a **string**.

See [section 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.1) of the RFC, where it reads:

> code_verifier = high-entropy cryptographic random STRING using the
> unreserved characters...

Later in the section, the authors recommend a method of generating the code_verifier string:

> It is RECOMMENDED that the output of
> a suitable random number generator be used to create a 32-octet
> sequence.  The octet sequence is then base64url-encoded to produce a
> 43-octet URL safe string to use as the code verifier.

This method of generating the code_verifier string is applied in the example in [Appendix B](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#appendix-B) that you cited in your question.

But, the fact remains that the code_verifier is a **string**.  Moreover, this is only a recommended way of generating the code_verifier string - there are many other ways of generating random strings, other than base64-encoding randomly generated bytes.

Your question pertains to the step where the code_verifier is hashed, to produce the code_challenge.  You ask:

> The part that seems strange is that the bytes from the first random byte sequence are not hashed to generate the challenge, the ascii bytes of the base64url-encoded string are hashed. Is there any reason for this?

When hashing strings, it is standard practice to take the hash of the ASCII bytes comprising the string.  This makes sense in this case, being that the code_verifier is in fact a string.

You also ask:

> Why not just hash the original bytes?

Bear in mind that these 'original bytes' are only present because the code_verifier string was generated as per the recommendation in section 4.1.  The spec does not mandate that the code_verifier must be generated in this fashion.  If the code_verifier was generated via some other method, there might not be any 'original bytes'.

Comment: "When hashing strings, it is standard practice to take the hash of the ASCII bytes comprising the string"

How so? Can you provide examples, because my experience with other cryptography designs is that the random bytes are hashed before it's encoded.

Comment: @JBaczuk, in that case, how would you take a hash of the string `hello world`?

Comment: sorry my question was unclear. My question is why hash the encoded bytes, why not just hash the random bytes. I.e. why has the string at all, why not hash it before it is encoded into a string?

Comment: I agree with you that typically it is the underlying bytes that are fed to crypto functions.  But, in this case, the method of generating the code_verifier string by base64-encoding random bytes is only a recommendation (see section 4.1 of the spec).  It's possible that the code_verifier string could be generated some other way.   I think you're fixating too much on how the code_verifier is generated in the example, as opposed to focusing on the fact that the code_verifier is just a random string, so it should be hashed the same way that you would hash any other string (e.g. 'hello world').

Comment: To say it another way - I generated a code_verifier string, not using the recommended method, but using another method.  Here it is: `FjIiZWnwvhl5bYp6jDJl6QQAUHULLwZumk4Q6RBp-_.~`  As you can see, it contains only unreserved characters, as required in section 4.1.  But, this is not base64 encoding, as you can see by the last two characters.  If we go by your logic, what would be the underlying bytes that we should hash?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the rationale. If it's just hashed as ASCII, there is nothing to be gained by encoding it. I.e. it doesn't afford any additional bytes per character since we are limited to url-friendly characters anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think that basically sums it up.  I must admit, when I first read your question, I saw it the same way as you.  It would seem more natural to hash the underlying bytes, than to hash the ascii of the base64 encoded underlying bytes.  It was only after I started reading the spec (especially section 4.1) that I understood why they are doing it this way.  I agree, it's confusing, until you realize that it's just a string that just happens to be created by base64 encoding (if you use their recommendation).